# Unable to Import Date Column from Excel through PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell

I am trying to pull an excel sheet through below PowerShell script which I need to write to a SQL Server later. The 'Report Date' column is unable to import any data.
Is there a problem with sytax somewhere? I have attached how my excel sheet looks like.

[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSTUJ.png)

```
$My_File_Date = $My_FileIN.BaseName.Replace("filename_","").Replace("_","")
$My_Formatted_Date = [datetime]::ParseExact($My_File_Date,"yyyyMMdd",$null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
$My_Fields_File = "$Headers_DIR\My_Fields.txt"
$My_Fields = @{}
$My_Fields = (Get-content "$My_Fields_File" -Delim ",").Replace(",","")
Convert-xlsToxlsx $My_FileIN $My_Converted_File
$My_Data = Import-XLSX -Path $My_Converted_File -Sheet 1 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
$My_Count = $My_Data.Count
$My_Data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Distributor -Value "Name Co."
$My_Data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "File Date" -Value $My_Formatted_Date
Write-Host "File imported - $My_Count records found ... " -NoNewline
Write-Host "Converting to Data Table"
$My_DataTable = 

 ($My_Data |
    Select-Object -Property Distributor,'File Date',@{l='Report Date';e={If ($_.'Report Date' -as [datetime]){$_.'[datetime]::ParseExact("Report Date","dd.MM.yyyy",$null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")'} else {[DBNULL]::Value}}},Country
  )





Distributor File Date  Report Date Country
----------- ---------  ----------- -------
Name Co.    09/06/2021             US     
Name Co.    09/06/2021             UK     
Name Co.    09/06/2021             GE
```

Comment: Seems like just a typo to me. `-as` to `-is`.

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala i tried -is still blank. am I formatting the data type correctly?

Comment: Oops, I missed that.. The expression should be: `[datetime]::ParseExact("$(_.'Report Date'","dd.MM.yyyy",$null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))` leave the single quotes out, and place the piped object in the parsing act.

Comment: The report date is still blank after trying this.


`Select-Object -Property Distributor,'File Date',@{l='Report Date';e={If ($_.'Report Date' -as [datetime]){$_.[datetime]::ParseExact("($_.'Report Date'","dd.MM.yyyy",$null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")} else {[DBNULL]::Value}}},Country
  ) `

Comment: `Select-Object -Property Distributor,'File Date',@{l='Report Date';e={If ($null -ne $_.'Report Date'){[datetime]::ParseExact("($_.'Report Date'","dd.MM.yyyy",$null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")} else {$null }}},Country `

Comment: Ah something is really weird in my case. I copy-pasted your code as it is but the 'Report Date' is coming with literally no data. i think it is more than formatting. did you check my excel sheet Abraham?

Comment: What does `$My_Data` look like after you do the `Import-XSLS` command.  Could you do `$My_Data | Get-Member` and add the results to to your post?

Comment: @Daniel - `$IM_Data | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Report Date"`


Name        MemberType   Definition                         
----        ----------   ----------                         
Report Date NoteProperty double Report Date=44356.2694990625

Comment: Show us your functions `Convert-xlsToxlsx` and `Import-XLSX`. Also, I don't see variables `$My_Converted_File` or `$Headers_DIR` defined anywhere.. Why define `$My_Fields` as Hashtable first and then overrule that with `Get-Content` ? You never use that variable, so why bother at all?

Comment: ok, how may I upload my functions here? can I upload .ps1 file somehow?

Comment: Use `[datetime]::FromOADate($_.'Report Date').ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')`

Comment: Also, instead of using this `Import-XLSX` function I would recommend looking into using `Import-Excel` function from [ImportExcel Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel It worked for me
`Select-Object -Property Distributor,'File Date',@{l='Report Date';e={If ($_.'Report Date'){[datetime]::FromOADate($_.'Report Date').ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')} else {[DBNULL]::Value}}},Country`

please write this as your answer...